# Returning from Admob Interstitial gives black screen

Tags: android, cocos2d-iphone, admob, apportable, spritebuilder

I'm using Apportable Indie for adding Admob to my game (made with SpriteBuilder). Everything works (Banner is showing and Interstitial) but when I click the Interstitial and return to the game it shows a black screen and no response. I've used the [AdNetworkTests](https://github.com/apportable/AdNetworkTests) as an example.

The code: `[interstitial_ presentFromRootViewController:[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController];`

1. Anybody else having this problem?
2. Is it a Apportable issue OR and Android issue

Comment: Hello, I only have the starter edition. I think you have e-mail support for the Indie Version, you could ask them directly. (Sorry I don't have any info for the problem though)

Comment: I send my project to Apportable and they are going to check it out. I'll post the results